# pdflatex configuration

Tags: pdftex

Is there a configuration (JSON, YAML, ini, anything...) file for **pdflatex.exe**? I find the following painful:

```
c:\ pdflatex.exe --shell-escape --enable-write18 --extra-mem-bot=10000000
--stack-size=20000 --synctex=1 --interaction=nonstopmode --include-
directory="C:\Users\hsmyers\Documents\Ultra Fractal 5\Formulas\" fn.tex
```

It also has the *minor* problem of an embedded typo that forces **pdflatex** to emit two stars `**` indicating that it is waiting for me to type the file name *sigh!*

[Edit] This was using MikTeX 2.9's pdflatex from the Win7 Pro's command line.

Comment: Try with `pdflatex fn.tex`. Probably you not need any option. BTW,  there are several TeX automation tools: rubber, latexmk, arara ... Run `texdoc arara`, for instance.

Comment: Usually this is saved in the configuration file of your editor.

Comment: A couple of things, this was run from the command line intentionally. the parameters were the ones needed. I have a variety of editors and was debugging a problem, that was not clear from ide runs—good suggests though!

Comment: Yes there is a configuration file. Exactly what it is called and where to put it depends on what TeX installation you have. Try the documentation for pdflatex on your system. For example in texlive, it's called texmf.cnf, but there are two files with that name, and you should only edit the correct one! If you use an IDE to edit your .tex files, that may also have a way to set the default options. (But you haven't told us the exact software you are using).

Comment: I was using MiKTeX 2.9's pdflatex from the Windows command line. Sorry, should have mentioned that!

Comment: You cannot need both `--shell-escape` and `--enable-write18` so at least one of the parameters is not needed. If you are debugging, you don't want `--interaction=nonstopmode`, surely? I don't understand the comment about the typo.

Comment: Didn't know the two were contradictory, thanks! Was not debugging pdflatex, but rather a tex file. There must be a typo (I hope) in that the command as given ignored the file name at the end. Or so I surmise.

Comment: `--shell-escape` and `--enable-write18` are not contradictory, they are alias. Some of your settings can be moved to ini-files (call `initexmf --edit-config-file pdflatex` and check the documentation).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks for that, could you give me a pointer to where in the documentation? I got far enough to know about initexmf but didn't see anything on what might go inside the .ini file?

Comment: https://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/runtimeparams.html

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I've modifies my pdflatex.ini file and can tell you that I still need to add shell-escape to either the file (somehow, not sure of the form) or the command line invocation. In any event, I am now trapped in the "Sorry, but pdflatex did not succeed." loop and don't know how to exit... That is what pdflatex says no matter what at least from the command line!

Answer (score 2):

Read the comments above for a description of how I got to the following as an answer to my question.

1. Yes, there is a config/ini file. It is called pdflatex.ini and in my particular instance, it lives at "c:\Users\hsmyers\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\config\pdflatex.ini".
2. I created it with a command line of "initexmf
   --edit-config-file=miktex\config\pdflatex.ini" NB. see @UlrikeFischer comment above, her invocation is shorter and works for her...
3. I added the following to the file: main_memory=2000000,EnableWrite18=p    ,extra-mem-bot=10000000,stack-size=20000
4. And then ran pdflatex again adding --shell-escape to the command line.

And as they say, *"that worked for me!"*